# PKAppDelegate.m missing

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.3

I'm having some difficulties in running the gbible Xcode Project. More precisely, I get the following error message:

> clang: error: no such file or directory:
>   '/Users/xxxx/Documents/xxxxx/gbible/gbible/PKAppDelegate.m' clang:
>   error: no input files Command
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   failed with exit code 1

Any ideas/suggestions on that?

Source link

https://github.com/photokandyStudios/gbible

Answer (score 0):

It's says that there is no file named "PKAppDelegate.m", and in repo i see that is missed. Try to donwload repo from another branch "v1.3:

```
git clone -b v1.3 https://github.com/photokandyStudios/gbible.git
```